# Neural Network not learning - python

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, jupyter-notebook

I implemented a NN, but it's not working. Somebody can help me to figure out, what is the problem? I try with simple, and, or , xor function. The cost function seems to decrease, but fail at the moment of classify, I set the iteration to 50,000, change the number of alpha (0.1,0.01,0.001), code two solution, vectorized way and one by one observation.

Here the viewer of notebook: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/Abreu0101/05f6fe35b08eac1162c7

DataSet:

```
def loadDataSet():
    X = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,0,0]])
    y = np.array([[1],[0],[0],[0]])
    return X,y
```

Code:

```
X,y = loadDataSet()
n_observations,n_features = X.shape
weights_1 = np.random.rand(2,3)
weights_2 = np.random.rand(1,3)

maxIter = 90000
for currentIter in range(maxIter):
    costError(weights_1,weights_2,currentIter)

    #FeedFodward
    z_1 = X.dot(weights_1.T)
    a_1 = np.hstack((np.ones((n_observations,1)),sigmoid(z_1)))

    z_2 = a_1.dot(weights_2.T)
    a_2 = sigmoid(z_2)

    #BackPropagation
    d_2 = (y - a_2) * sigmoid(z_2,derivate=True)
    d_1 = (d_2.dot(weights_2))[:,1:]

    alpha = 1 #Learning Rate
    weights_2 = weights_2 + alpha * d_2.T.dot(a_1)
    weights_1 = weights_1 + alpha * d_1.T.dot(X)
```

Cost Function:

```
def costError(w_1,w_2,currentIter):
    z_1 = X.dot(w_1.T)
    a_1 = np.hstack((np.ones((n_observations,1)),sigmoid(z_1)))

    z_2 = a_1.dot(w_2.T)
    a_2 = sigmoid(z_2)

    sumError = np.sum(a_2)
    print("Error : %f , Iter: %d"%(sumError,currentIter))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code (or a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) directly to SO.

Comment: Thanks Richard for the recommendation, I did it. Although I had put a link to a notebook, is it not valid?

Comment: Check out this [meta-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code) to see some of the reasons for posting directly to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) change d_2 and d_1 to:

```
d_2 = (y - a_2)# * sigmoid(z_2,derivate=True)
d_1 = (d_2.dot(weights_2))[:,1:]*sigmoid(z_1,derivate=True)
```

In fact i don't know why `* sigmoid(z_2,derivate=True)` needs to be commented out, but without it nn converges faster, and every implementation of nn that i saw was implemented without multiplying on gradient of sigmoid function of output level.

2) What means `sumError = np.sum(a_2)` ? You need to take into account difference between predicted and actual values:

```
sumError = np.mean((y-a_2)**2)
```

Your derivatives calculated for this loss function.

Comment: Thank you! @Olologin. Now it's working. I lack the derivate of z_1.

I use the derivate of the sigmoid, because in this paper (https://www4.rgu.ac.uk/files/chapter3%20-%20bp.pdf) said:
The “Output(1-Output)” term is necessary in the equation because of the Sigmoid Function – if we were only using a threshold neuron it would just be (Target – Output).

But, as you point out, converges faster without the derivative.